Is there a way to securely store cookies using HTTPCookieStorage
I recently discovered that HTTPCookieStorage stores my application's secure JWT tokens as searchable text in a file located at <App Bundle Path>/Library/Cookies/<bundle id>.binarycookies.
I had previously presumed that Apple would encrypt the tokens before storing them to disc, especially given that they are marked as secure tokens.
I've searched the Internet, and most responses admit that this is true, but suggest that this is not an issue because of Apple's Data Protection technology (which uses 256-bit encryption when the device is locked). However, when the device is unlocked or jailbroken, these cookies would be readily accessible. I want to ensure that my application's JWT tokens are encrypted even when the device is unlocked or jailbroken.
I've searched the documentation for HTTPCookieStorage for any settings to encrypt secure cookies before saving them to disc and found no built-in option.

cookies are not really made to be secure. If you want something to be stored securely, don's store it to persistent cookie storage.

Yes. I hadn't realized that HTTPCookieStorage was storing the cookies insecurely until now. My understanding was that if a cookie is marked as secure, it's the client's responsibility to store it securely. I had presumed that Apple would have automatically implemented secure storage. I was able to find a solution (see below).

The secure flag for a cookie only means that it can only be used with https rather than http. However that doesn't say anything about storing it on the device.

Turns out that HTTPCookieStorage can be subclassed.
I ended up implementing an in-memory solution. This could easily be modified to use Keychain. In-memory is good enough for my current solution.
class SecureCookieStorage : HTTPCookieStorage {
    private var inMemoryCookieStorage : [String: [HTTPCookie]] = [:]
    private let cookieQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "secure.cookie.storage", attributes: .concurrent)

    override func getCookiesFor(_ task: URLSessionTask, completionHandler: @escaping ([HTTPCookie]?) -> Void) {
        guard let host = task.currentRequest?.url?.host else {
            completionHandler(nil)
            return
        }
        
        cookieQueue.sync { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            let cookies = self.inMemoryCookieStorage[host]
            completionHandler(cookies)
        }
    }
    
    override func storeCookies(_ cookies: [HTTPCookie], for task: URLSessionTask) {
        guard let host = task.currentRequest?.url?.host else {
            return
        }
        
        cookieQueue.async(flags: .barrier) { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.inMemoryCookieStorage[host] = cookies
        }
    }
}

Then, set up URLSessionConfiguration to use SecureCookieStorage
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.httpCookieStorage = SecureCookieStorage()
let urlSession = URLSession(configuration:configuration)


If you really need it to be "secure" you shouldn't store it into the HTTPCookieStorage. Rather use the Keychain and then add the cookie whenever needed to your request. But I don't get why it needs to be so private, that the user can't read it. If they want they could also intercept the cookie when sent with a request.
